# Android check box not much visible in a Dialog as in an activity

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am working in an android application and I uses android checkbox in my application. When I used checkbox in an activity, it is very visible and blackish. But when I use the same check box in an Custom dialog, the checkbox becomes very lite. I want to make the checkbox in the dialog a little more blackish as in appears in an activity with out a custom checkbox. Please suggest me an appropriate solution.

```
private void showIndividualDeleteDialog(List<CommonDomain> individuals) {

    try {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SessionActivity.this);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.individualssession);
        final IndividualAdaptor adaptor = new IndividualAdaptor(
                individuals, getApplicationContext());

        ((ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.individualsListView))
                .setAdapter(adaptor);
        dialog.show();

        ((ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.individualDeleteButton))
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        List<CommonDomain> selectedUser = adaptor.mLstClientInGroup;
                        String xml = makeRemoveIndividualsXml(selectedUser);

                        new StopSessionAsynk(dialog)
                                .execute(new String[] { xml });

                    }
                });

        ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.individualCancelButton))

        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button_gradient"
        android:paddingTop="1dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/individualCancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:onClick="onCancelButton_Click"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/individualDeleteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_btn_selector"
            android:onClick="onDeleteButton_Click" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#151515"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/individuals_delete_HeadText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/individualsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#D5D5D5"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView row xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:minHeight="44dp"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/individualNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/individualsCheckBox"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/individualsCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:clickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the code for the custom dialogue

Comment: @insomniac..Please look into ma code..

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the theme you are using. Use same theme as your Activity for your Dialog.
check out [this](http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/09/theme-android-dialog/)

Comment: Yes, I am using themes in my application.But I tried to put the same theme in my dialog, but the dialog become full screen and no change to the check box appears..

Comment: can you post the screenshots of activity and dialog. and also please post the code of xml layout of Dialog.